# vs2010 Linq to SQL -- adding an entity from my DBML

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

I think I may be going crazy here...

Anyways, I have a DBML with a table 'User' in it. Pretty simple stuff --
From within a class, I have the following:

```
BusinessDataContext businessDataContext = new BusinessDataContext();

var user = new User();
user.FirstName = FirstName;
user.LastName = LastName;
user.MiddleInitial = MiddleInitial;
user.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;

/*
  There's no businessDataContext.User.Add method -- 
  There's a bunch of generic collection methods with the <> symbols 
  (Aggregate, All, Any...)
  Am I just too tired and missing something basic 
  or did something simple change with vs 2010?
*/

businessDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I think I really just need sleep. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx)? i.e. `businessDataContext.User.InsertOnSubmit(user);` or `businessDataContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);`?